# Как отправить сообщение вк одним сообщением бот Python

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, join, бот

Всем привет. У меня есть бот на Пайтон который присылает расписание в вк. Проблема в том что каждую пару он присылает отдельным сообщением, мне надо сделать так,чтобы все пары пришли одним сообщением введите сюда описание изображения. Пробовал методом .join, но также

```
                r = requests.post('https://uaviak.ru/pages/raspisanie-/#pos2')                
            soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
            ras = soup.find('div', class_="scrolling-text pos2").text.split('\n')
            das = soup.find('div', class_="scrolling-text pos2").text.split('\n')
            for ur in ras:
                if ur.find('21ис-3') >=0:
                    parameters = [ur]
                    full_ras = '\n'.join(parameters)
                    print(full_ras)
                    vk_session.method('messages.send' , {'user_id' : id, 'message' : full_ras, 'random_id' : 0})
```

[image: Вк бот]

[image: Код]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

№ 1

```
full_ras = ''
for ur in ras:
    if ur.find('21ис-3') >= 0:
        full_ras += f'{ur}\n'

print(full_ras)
```

№ 2

```
parameters = []
for ur in ras:
    if ur.find('21ис-3') >=0:
        parameters.append(ur)

full_ras = '\n'.join(parameters)
print(full_ras)
```

Comment: спасибо большое, вариант 2 подошел